# Serialize and Deserialize Dictionary to binary

Tags: c#, dictionary, serialization

I want to make a binary serialize of a dictionory object.

This is my dictionary object

```
public Dictionary<int, UserSessionInfo> UserSessionLookupTable = new Dictionary<int, UserSessionInfo>();
```

This is my UserSessionInfo class

```
public class UserSessionInfo
    {
        public int SessionId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public Guid SessionGuid { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
        public bool IsActiveUser { get; set; }
        public RowState State { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I am creating a dictionary entry while on user login

```
UserSessionLookupTable.Add(SessionId, userSessionInfoLogin);
```

Now I want to binary serialize UserSessionLookupTable object. How Can I do this?

I have tried

```
var binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                var mStream = new MemoryStream();
                binFormatter.Serialize(mStream, UserSessionLookupTable);
                mStream.ToArray();
```

Will it works?

Also how can I remove an entry from dictionary while a user log off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following is the extension methods to use the standard .Net binary serializer, also to deserialize and compress and decompress it reduce the size of byte array:

```
public static class ObjectSerialize
    {
        public static byte[] Serialize(this Object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, obj);

                var compressed = Compress(memoryStream.ToArray());
                return compressed;
            }
        }

        public static Object DeSerialize(this byte[] arrBytes)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                var decompressed = Decompress(arrBytes);

                memoryStream.Write(decompressed, 0, decompressed.Length);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }
        }

        public static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
        {
            byte[] compressesData;

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zip = new GZipStream(outputStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                {
                    zip.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
                }

                compressesData = outputStream.ToArray();
            }

            return compressesData;
        }

        public static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
        {
            byte[] decompressedData;

            using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input))
                {
                    using (var zip = new GZipStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        zip.CopyTo(outputStream);
                    }
                }

                decompressedData = outputStream.ToArray();
            }

            return decompressedData;
        }
    }
```

However I would suggest that you use the `ProtoBuf` for binary serialization, more details [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/csharptutorial#compiling-your-protocol-buffers)

It would work as simple as:

```
 using ProtoBuf

 var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

 // Serialize the Data to Stream
 byte[] data =  Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, UserSessionLookupTable);
```

Here also you can include compression and decompression suggested above, in my experience ProBuf is much faster than standard Serialize.

For modifying anything in the dictionary you need to `deserialize` by calling the method above in case of standard serializer:

```
var userSessionLookUpDeserialize =   
   (Dictionary<int,UserSessionInfo>)data.DeSerialize();
```

Following is the code for the ProtoBuf:

```
 var userSessionLookUpDeserialize = Serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, UserSessionInfo>>(new MemoryStream(deCompresseBytes));
```

Now make changes to the `userSessionLookUpDeserialize`